# Split 1 XML to multiple after specific tag using PHP

Tags: php, xml

i want to split 1 XML file on multiple smaller one, always from tag . As soon PHP is the only language i know a bit i decide to use it.

My try looks like:

```
$xnl_file = "xml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xnl_file);
$my_file = 0;
foreach ($xml as $value){

    $CountryOrganizationId = "<CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
    $PartnershipId = "<PartnershipId>".$xml->Partnership->PartnershipId."</PartnershipId>";
    $OwnerId = "<OwnerId>".$xml->Partnership->OwnerId."<OwnerId>";
    $PartnerIdList = "<PartnerIdList><String>".$xml->Partnership->PartnerIdList->String."</String></PartnerIdList>";
    $CountryOrganizationId_contact = "<Contract><CountryOrganizationId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->CountryOrganizationId."</CountryOrganizationId>";
    $ContractId = "<ContractId>".$xml->Partnership->Contract->CountryOrganizationId."</ContractId>";
    $Role = "<LaborRateList><LaborRateDetail><Role>".$xml->Partnership->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail->Role."</Role>";
    $Category = "<Category>".$xml->Partnership->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail->Category."</Category>";
    $Rate1 = "<Rate Cur='CZK' Unit='h' MinValue='0' MaxValue='0'>".$xml->Partnership->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail->Rate."</Rate></LaborRateDetail>";
    echo $OwnerId;
    echo "<br>";
    $my_file = ($my_file + 1).".xml";
    //mkdir("new", 0700); Create subfolder
    $handle = fopen('xml/'.$my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates files in XML folder  
    $data = "<Partnership>".$CountryOrganizationId.$PartnershipId.$OwnerId.$PartnerIdList.$CountryOrganizationId_contact.$ContractId.$Role.$Category.$Rate1."</Partnership>";
    fwrite($handle, $data);  
    }
```

As you can see i just load XML file and foreach  getting values and adding them to variabiles and then trying to print again. isn't there some faster way just to CUT when find a tag Partnership?

My XML looks like:

```
<PartnershipList xmlns="URL">
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>07</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:17:46.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T10:49:18.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_58AB4635-D9C6-A04E</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>07</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Alfa Romeo</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
 <Partnership>
  <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
  <PartnershipId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</PartnershipId>
  <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
  <PartnerIdList>
   <String>MM-O-2A10BCF</String>
  </PartnerIdList>
  <Contract>
   <CountryOrganizationId>CZ</CountryOrganizationId>
   <ContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</ContractId>
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
   <IdBlockCodeList>
    <IDBlockCode>
     <IDBlockCode>51</IDBlockCode>
     <Entry>100</Entry>
    </IDBlockCode>
   </IdBlockCodeList>
   <VehicleKind>Car</VehicleKind>
   <RepairKind>BodyRepair</RepairKind>
   <ManufacturerCode>10</ManufacturerCode>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <CreatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</CreatedBy>
   <CreationTimeStamp>2014-09-09T15:22:27.000</CreationTimeStamp>
   <UpdatedBy>MM-P-69F997009BBFB4FC2C</UpdatedBy>
   <UpdateTimeStamp>2014-10-15T13:11:36.000</UpdateTimeStamp>
   <FirstVersionContractId>Contract_F5134A37-F39A-823A</FirstVersionContractId>
   <OwnerId>MM-O-BDD15299</OwnerId>
   <Manufacturer>10</Manufacturer>
   <VehicleType>Car</VehicleType>
   <VehicleAgeFrom>0</VehicleAgeFrom>
   <VehicleAgeTo>0</VehicleAgeTo>
   <ClaimType>Unknown</ClaimType>
  </Contract>
  <Description>Citroën</Description>
  <PartnerId>MM-O-2A10BCF</PartnerId>
 </Partnership>
```

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to create a XML file for each `<Partnership>` element. This is quite easy with DOM.

The value of `xmlns="URL"` is not only an URL - it is the namespace of the document. It defines the XML format the elements are part of. This is a relevant information.

DOM is all about nodes. Anything in an XML document is a node. Here are element nodes, text nodes and many more. Xpath allows you to select nodes and DOM has methods to create, clone and import them.

```
// create a dom and load the xml document
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->load($xmlFile);
// get an Xpath object and register a prefix for the used namespace
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ps', 'urn:missing-namespace-uri');

// fetch all namespace nodes and iterate them
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//ps:Partnership') as $index => $partnership) {
  // create a target document
  $target = new DOMDocument();
  // import the partnership node and append it to the target document node
  $target->appendChild($target->importNode($partnership, TRUE));
  // save it
  echo $target->save(($index + 1).'.xml');
}
```

Hint: Building XML as text requires escaping (`htmlspecialchars()`). If using DOM, it will take care of the escaping for you.

Comment: Hi ThW, thanks for your answer. You understand it right. Anyway it looks i am doing something wrong. I copy your code and just add $xml file to it to test it and i get no output.

Can you give me a bit more info? Thanks

Comment: Demo: https://eval.in/218351 , uses strings not files. Make sure that you replaced the `'urn:missing-namespace-uri'` with the actual namespace.

Comment: Hi again ThW, actualy you are right, if i copy your code it works, but i think there is some problem with loading XML from file or IDK. When i make $xml = "xml.xml" instead of your XML loadad as string i get an ERROR:`

`Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\file.php on line 6`

Comment: Compare the source, The demo uses strings, not files. So it uses `loadXML()/saveXML()` and not `load()/save()`.

Comment: Sorry man, looks i am idiot but 
I can try however i want:
First try:
http://pastebin.com/r0ER7jdi (also with error)
Second try
http://pastebin.com/Rqw6vqzz (ALSO WITH ERROR)

Comment: Provide a filename for `->save()`?

Comment: Ofc, i should know that, sorry and really thanks for helping and patiance