# PHP Parsing XML

Tags: php, xml

i am having some problem with parsing XML.

**What i am doing:**
I am spliting 1 XML to many and also editing few things for new one. And it works!!

**Where is problem:**
After Parsing not all parts are same, to be more specifc in some of them are just 2 Labor Rate Details, in another there can be 5.:

So some looks like:

```
  <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
```

And another:

```
   <LaborRateList>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Labor</Role>
     <Category>1</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">250.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
    <LaborRateDetail>
     <Role>Paint</Role>
     <Category>2</Category>
     <Rate Cur="CZK" Unit="h" MinValue="0" MaxValue="0">350.0</Rate>
    </LaborRateDetail>
   </LaborRateList>
```

i was trying to find out how to not insert anything if there is no more labor rates.
What i try was check if there is anything in variabile and if not write nothing so my code looks like:

```
//RATE3 PART     
var_dump($value->Contract->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail[2]->Role);
    if ($value->Contract->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail[2]->Role == 0)
//SOME CODE HERE
```

But i am getting error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\index.php on line 23
NULL 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\provisioning\index.php on line 24
```

My FULL CODE can be found on http://pastebin.com/12HiHEcu , it's my last try which is not working  :(

Can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: So how are you parsing them? You can't just access an XML node in a "normal" string. You will need to use some kind of library to parse it.

Comment: EDITED and added full code

Comment: This is easier with DOM (because of the node methods), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774674/split-1-xml-to-multiple-after-specific-tag-using-php/26776687#26776687

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you could use another foreach to do that:

```
foreach($value->Contract->LaborRateList->LaborRateDetail as $laborRateDetails) {
  //Do your stuff
}
```